# javascript regular expression test for 6 digit numbers only. comma seperated

Tags: javascript, regex

and so this must pass:

```
454555, 939999 , 019999    ,727663
```

its for a user entering 6 digit invoice numbers. it should fail if a number is 5 or 7 digit and not 6. so `1234567, 123456` should fail, as one set is more than 6 numbers.

So far I have :

```
[0-9]{6}(\s*,*,\s*[0-9]{6})*
```

which only draw back is that it accepts 7 or more digit numbers. cant figure out if its even possible at this point to do both, test for 6 digits separated by a comma and one or more space, and all the digits have to be only 6 digits and fail if one is not.

any help appreciated. regular expressions are not my forte.

thanks

Norman

Comment: it should also pass if just one number is entered: 333222

Comment: Did you tried adding anchors - `^` and `$` at the ends?

Comment: @mvw That works just fine; I recommend that you delete your misleading comment.

Comment: You have `,*` in your regex; do you really mean to allow `123456,,,,,123456` as valid? How about input with only whitespace, e.g. `123456 123456`; is that valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to validate the full string you can use this regex.

```
^(\s*\d{6}\s*)(,\s*\d{6}\s*)*,?\s*$
```

It works with six digits only, and you have to enter at least one 6 digit number.
It also works if you have a trailing comma with whitespaces.

Comment: This will match: `123456 123456` because the comma is optional.

Comment: @nickb is correct, and it will even match `123456123456` because the whitespace is also optional.

Comment: I selected this version because its the 1st one I tested and it meets ALL my criterias. accepts one comma between numbers (not 2) and allows spaces. and no comma at beginning. So its perfect. I did not try the others, so they may work fine, but this was the first that works. Thanks to @jesko and all that responded.

Answer (score 6):

You can write it using regex like the function below.

```
const isPassword = (password: string) => /^\d{6}$/gm.test(password);
```

And here is an example test file below.

```
  test('should recognize a valid password', () => {
    expect(isPassword('123456')).toBe(true);
    expect(isPassword('000000')).toBe(true);
  });

  test('should recognize an invalid password', () => {
    expect(isPassword('asdasda1234')).toBe(false);
    expect(isPassword('1234567')).toBe(false);
    expect(isPassword('a123456a')).toBe(false);
    expect(isPassword('11.11.11')).toBe(false);
    expect(isPassword('aaaaaa')).toBe(false);
    expect(isPassword('eeeeee')).toBe(false);
    expect(isPassword('......')).toBe(false);
    expect(isPassword('werwerwerwr')).toBe(false);
  });
```

Comment: What question are you answering? They want to match a **list** of number comma separated.

Answer (score 2):

It's accepting more than six digit numbers because you're not anchoring the text, and for some odd reason you're optionally repeating the comma. Try something like this:

```
^[0-9]{6}(?:\s*,\s*[0-9]{6})*$
```

Also note that `[0-9]` is equivalent to `\d`, so this can be rewritten more concisely as:

```
^\d{6}(?:\s*,\s*\d{6})*$
```

Comment: This will fail if there is whitespace at the beginning or end.

Comment: @JustinMorgan - Yes, it's left to the OP to either trim the leading / trailing whitespace, or to add `\s*` after the anchors. That is, of course, if the whitespace is an issue, which is ambiguous based on the OP.

Comment: Yeah, I think that was a mistake, but he was unclear about it. Fair enough, I've removed the downvote to give you the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex does not match `7` digits in a row, but it also doesn't enforce that it matches the whole string. It just has to match some substring in the string, so it would also match each of these:

```
"1234512345612345612345"
"NaNaNaN  123456,    123456 BOOO!"
"!@#$%^&*({123456})*&^%$#@!"
```

Just add the start of string (`^`) and end of string (`$`) anchors to enforce that the whole string matches and it will work correctly:

```
^[0-9]{6}(\s*,*,\s*[0-9]{6})*$
```

Also note that `,*,` could be shortened to `,+`, and if you only want one comma in a row, just use `,`, not `,*` or `,+`.

You can also replace `[0-9]` with `\d`:

```
^\d{6}(\s*,\s*\d{6})*$
```

Comment: These will fail if there is whitespace at the beginning or end.

Comment: @JustinMorgan Yup! That's probably a good thing, since the OP wrote there's like that originally.

Comment: Hmm...I think that was a mistake, but he was unclear about it. I'll remove the downvote for the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Using only regex:

```
var commaSeparatedSixDigits = /^(?:\d{6}\s*,\s*)*\d{6}$/;
if (myInput.test(commaSeparatedSixDigits)) console.log( "Is good!" );
```

This says:

- `^` - Starting at the beginning of the string
- `(?:…)*` - Find zero or more of the following:

  - `\d{6}` - six digits
  - `\s*` - maybe some whitespace
  - `,` - a literal comma
  - `\s*` - maybe some whitespace
- `\d{6}` - Followed by six digits
- `$` - Followed by the end of the string

Alternatively:

```
var commaSeparatedSixDigits = /^\s*\d{6}(?:\s*,\s*\d{6})*\s*$/;
```

*I leave it as an exercise to you to decipher what's different about this.*

---

Using JavaScript + regex:

```
function isOnlyCommaSeparatedSixDigitNumbers( str ){
  var parts = srt.split(/\s*,\s*/);
  for (var i=parts.length;i--;){
    // Ensure that each part is exactly six digit characters
    if (! /^\d{6}$/.test(parts[i])) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: The `\d{6}` in the capture group should be at the end, not the beginning.

Comment: @AaronDufour You are right; I had just edited it (another way) to fix that :)

Comment: Your first pattern will fail if there is whitespace at the beginning or end.

Comment: @JustinMorgan That is true. Also if there is a comma before or after the list. Also if there are multiple commas in a row. These are all possibly desirable, but not specified by the OP either way.

Answer (score 0):

There isn;t any real need for a regexp. Limit the input to only 6 characters, only accept numbers and ensure that the input has 6 digits (not show here). So you would need:

HTML

```
<input type='text' name='invoice' size='10' maxlength='6' value='' onkeypress='evNumersOnly(event);'>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
function evNumbersOnly( evt ) {
  //---  only accepts numbers
  //--- this handles incompatabilities between browsers
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  //--- this handles incompatabilities between browsers
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  //--- convert key number to a letter
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]/;      // Allowable characters 0-9.+-,
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    //--- this prevents the character from being displayed
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of complication here. Sounds to me like what you want is pretty simple:

```
/^(\d{6},)*\d{6}$/
```

Then we account for whitespace:

```
/^\s*(\d{6}\s*,\s*)*\d{6}\s*$/
```

But as others have noted, this is actually quite simple in JavaScript without using regex:

```
function check(input) {
    var parts = input.split(',');
    for (var i = 0, n = parts.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (isNaN(+parts[i].trim())) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Tested in the Chrome JavaScript console.